# Unsubscribing events in case variable closure

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, closures, anonymous-methods

I'm always try to unsubscribe events where it possible and may. **In case when variable closure happen I do the following**:

```
int someVar;

EventHandler moveCompleted = null;
moveCompleted = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    //here is variable closure
    someVar = 5;
    //...
    moveStoryboard.Completed -= moveCompleted;
};

moveStoryboard.Completed += moveCompleted;
```

But I don't want to use anonymous method and I think this is not good way.
Please give me some advice or code samples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does 'In case when variable closure happen' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whats wrong with:

```
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyEvent += OnSomeEventHandlerToMyLocalClassWhichOfcourseIsABadPractice;
    }

    protected void OnSomeEventHandlerToMyLocalClassWhichOfcourseIsABadPractice(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyEvent -= OnSomeEventHandlerToMyLocalClassWhichOfcourseIsABadPractice;
    }
}
```

Comment: In case when I have a local variable in constructor how can I use it in OnSomeEventHandlerToMyLocalClassWhichOfcourseIsABadPractice ?

Comment: @Arterius - In that case, make it a class member.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an anonymous function, it's much easier:

```
moveStoryboard.Completed += HandleStoryboardCompleted;

...

private void HandleStoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff...
    moveStoryboard.Completed -= HandleStoryboardCompleted;
}
```

That will actually create another instance of `EventHandler` each time the method is called, but because that instance will be *equal* to the one used to subscribe (same method with the same target) it will be fine to use for unsubscription.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your answer. It's an honor for me. But I'm interested in case when variable closure happen.

Comment: @Arterius: You've said you don't want to use anonymous functions, which is precisely when variables *are* captured. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to use anonymous functions or not?

Comment: I thought maybe use of Dictionary<object, object> may help to hold variable I need and then after using remove from Dictionary.

Comment: If usage of anonymous methods is precisely when variables are captured then I will continue write a code as shown in question. I just want to now is there some good practice to do same without using anonymous methods.

Comment: @Arterius: Well, anonymous methods and lambda expressions - both of which count as "anonymous functions".